# GitHub Actions resolve wrong Node.js path

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, github-actions

I am running my tests in Jest and through GitHub actions. Unfortunately, it resolves the path incorrect.

In my [source file](https://github.com/andreasremdt/simple-translator/blob/0f25e4f490361a7bc8779827b137367d6860c62e/src/translator.js#L324), I use the following logic to require a JSON from the same project directory:

```js
const json = require(require('path').resolve('.') + 'i18n', 'en.json');
```

In Jest, the path is mocked by `jest.mock`:

```js
jest.mock(require('path').resolve('.', 'i18n', 'en.json'), () => {
  return { title: 'English title', paragraph: 'Hello World' };
});
```

Locally this works fine, but when I push the changes to GitHub actions, the name of project folder is duplicated:

```
Cannot find module '/home/runner/work/simple-translator/simple-translator/i18n/en.json' from 'tests/translator.node.test.js'
```

I think it should just contain `simple-translator` once.
You can see a live example of the failing workflow [here](https://github.com/andreasremdt/simple-translator/pull/16/checks?check_run_id=919717246).
And that's the entire [test that fails](https://github.com/andreasremdt/simple-translator/blob/v2/tests/translator.node.test.js#L76).

Do you have any idea why the path resolution in GitHub Actions is not working properly?

Comment: We have the double repo-name as well in our workflows, but everything works fine. But it would be very interesting why they contain it twice..
Try using process.cwd() or the GitHub Environment var GitHub.workspace

Comment: I tried it with process.cwd() and __dirname, without success. The only thing left to test is GitHub.workspace

Comment: Also seeing this in an unrelated node.js application when using mocha in 2022. However the github actions docs for the GITHUB_WORKSPACE environment variable suggest this may be the truth: "For example, /home/runner/work/my-repo-name/my-repo-name."

Answer (score 0):

Let me try, though I am not familiar with jest or github CI process...
The mock json file generated by test procedure is at `tests/i18n/en.json`, while your working process is looking for a path `` `${moduleHomeRoot}/i18n/en.json` `` . I guess you should add '..' into the jest.mock, as:

```
jest.mock(require('path').resolve('..', 'i18n', 'en.json'), () => {
  return { title: 'English title', paragraph: 'Hello World' };
});
```